# C# Double.ToString() performance issue

Tags: c#, .net

I have the following method to convert a double array to a `List<string>`:

```
    static Dest Test(Source s)
    {
        Dest d = new Dest();

        if (s.A24 != null)
        {
            double[] dd = s.A24;

            int cnt = dd.Length;

            List<string> lst = new List<string>();

            for (int i = 0; i < cnt; i++)
                lst.Add(((double)dd[i]).ToString());

            d.A24 = lst;
        }
        else
        {
            d.A24 = null;
        }

        return d;
    }
```

Doing a List.Add() in a loop seems like the fastest way according to my benchmarks beating all the various LINQ and Convert tricks.

This is *really* slow. 2400ms for a million calls (Any CPU, prefer 64-bit). So I was experimenting with various ways to make it faster. Let's assume I cannot cache the source or dest lists, etc obviously.

So anyways, I stumbled across something weird here... if I change the lst.Add() line to cast to a decimal instead of a double, it is much, MUCH faster.  900ms vs 2400ms.

**Here's my questions**

1) decimal has greater accuracy then double, so I shouldn't lose anything in the type cast, correct?

2) why is the Decimal.ToString() so much faster then Double.ToString()?

3) is this a reasonable optimization, or am I missing some key detail where this will come back to bite me?

I'm not concerned about using up a little bit more memory, I am only concerned about performance.

Nothing sophisticated for the test data at this point, just using:

```
s.A24 = new double[] { 1.2, 3.4, 5.6 };
```

Comment: Can you post a [mcve]? By the way, using LinQ to call `dd.Count()` when you could use dd.Length is unnecessary.

Comment: Is `lst.AddRange(dd.Select(x => x.ToString()));` any faster?

Comment: What are the values, how much precision do you need from them, and what format do you need them in? (I see the same behaviour by the way...)

Comment: Note that while `decimal` has greater precision, it has a smaller range than `double` - and doesn't handle infinity or NaN. If you know that all your values *will* be in the range of `decimal`, then converting to that is reasonable.

Comment: @nvoigt -- oops... Typo. I changed it to .Length... Maybe slightly faster. Now its like 2300ms.

Comment: @MattRowland -- Nope. Slower. 2500ms. The main expense is not on the list, its on Double.ToString().

Comment: You can also initialise the list to the size you need: `List<string> lst = new List<string>(cnt);`

Comment: @nvoigt -- that doesn't help in this case.

Comment: @JonSkeet -- ah... yeah... that might come back to bite me :). Crap...

Comment: The fastest way to optimize this is not to do it, by the way. That may sound flippant, but converting data to strings is almost literally the last thing you want to do (possibly just before you send the data over the wire because you don't want to use a binary interchange format, or before you present the data to the end user, but that's not usually a bottleneck). While the data is bouncing around in your process, you want to keep it as-is. String formatting is *expensive*, especially for something as many-faceted as `Double`.

Comment: Well, it definitely has something to do with the 64-bit build on my machine.  If I turn on "prefer 32-bit", performance of double.ToString improves enormously (by more than a factor of 2).

Comment: @JeroenMostert, yeah, I'm doing it at the end. Probably a rare case in reality, just something I need to support in my engine.

Comment: @Kyle -- yeah, I get the same thing on my 2 test machines as well. 833ms vs. 2400ms. Gotta be some performance glitch somewhere. 64bit vs 32bit can't be that much overhead... I did check in ILSpy and the same C# gets emitted between 64bit vs. 32bit.

Comment: For what it's worth, I wrote a quick/dirty test (written out in an answer so you can see it) and the performance was roughly equivalent, with the decimal taking slightly longer more often than not. At any rate, the beat of the code was taking in the range of 280-320 MS (3.3 GHz Core i5-4590, 16 GB), so there's something seemingly goofy going on in your test case.

Answer (score 2):

For what it's worth, I ran the following and got different results, with decimal usually taking slightly longer (but both calls of the calls to lst.Add() and number.ToString() being roughly equivalent).

What type of collection is A24 in your code? I wouldn't be surprised if the additional overhead you're seeing is actually in casting or something you're not currently looking at.

```
var iterations = 1000000;

var lst = new List<string>();

var rnd = new Random();
var dblArray = new double[iterations];
for (var i = 0; i < iterations; i++)
    //INTERESTING FINDING FROM THE COMMENTS
    //double.ToString() is faster if this line is rnd.NextDouble()
    //but decimal.ToString() is faster if hard-coding the value "3.5" 
    //(despite the overhead of casting to decimal)
    dblArray[i] = rnd.NextDouble();

var sw = new Stopwatch();
sw.Start();
for (var i = 0; i < iterations; i++)
    lst.Add(dblArray[i].ToString());
sw.Stop();
//takes 280-300 MS
Debug.WriteLine("Double loop MS: " + sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);

//reset list
lst = new List<string>();
sw.Restart();
for (var i = 0; i < iterations; i++)
    lst.Add(((decimal)dblArray[i]).ToString());
sw.Stop();
//takes 280-320 MS
Debug.WriteLine("Decimal loop MS: " + sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
```

Comment: You're doing decimal *arithmetic* as well though... the OP isn't. They're just casting an existing `double` value.

Comment: Second `sw.Start()` call is wrong. Change it to `Restart()`.

Comment: All of you are right! Thanks! I sometimes code too quickly/sloppily with SO answers. :-/

Comment: The updated version is a truer test of List.Add() and ToString() performance. I'm still concluding ToString() isn't the problem per se, barring further evidence. One other possibility is the numbers being stored result in longer strings in OP's case, though more info is needed.

Comment: source data collection is just a double[].

Comment: And you're seeing FASTER performance casting it to a decimal?!? For what it's worth, casting to decimal results in a 25% performance degradation for me.

Comment: Replace `rnd.NextDouble()` with `3.5` and you should see a difference. (Also, you can just remove the list altogether and just call `.ToString()` without using the result, and bump the number of iterations by a factor 10 to reduce jitter.) Yes, the length makes a difference.

Comment: @JeroenMostert - Interesting. How curious. I even wondered if something was occasionally getting rounded in the cast, but the printed representation of "3.5" is always "3.5" whether double or decimal. Also, the decimal does indeed ToString() faster (despite the casting) when using "3.5" (but not when using random doubles)!

Comment: @Colin, hmm.. yeah, I tested with kinda short doubles lol. Not a good test I know, I was just shocked at how slow that is.

Answer (score 1):

A Decimal and Double are often confused and interchanged, but they are completely different animals at the processor level.  If I had to imagine writing the code to for Double.ToString(), I can see the problem... It's hard.  Comparatively, writing the code for Decimal.ToString() shouldn't be much more difficult than Int32.ToString().  I'm sure if you compare Int32.ToString() to Decimal.ToString() you will find they results are very close.

FYI: Double and Float(Single) are not exact, and many numbers can't be expressed in a Double.  In your example, you give 1.2 which is really 1 + 1/5.  That can't exist as a true double (even if the VS IDE covers for it).  You would get something like 1.1999999999999998.  If you want performance, use a Decimal.

Comment: On my system, `Decimal.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)` is about 1.6 times as slow as `Int32.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)`; `Double.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)` is about 3.5 times as slow (tested with a simple `Stopwatch`-fenced loop, no `List.Add` involved). So you're not far off, though "very close" is a bit of an exaggeration.

Comment: Darn... yeah, I think doing the decimal cast will work for 99% of the cases out there. The decimal can even hold spatial points at full accuracy. Guess I'll just have to live with the double overhead. Can't really look at the code for Double.ToString() since .NET actually calls a native method inside of the CLR to do the formatting.

Comment: Also, one other interesting note, if you specify Prefer 32bit, the code is substantially faster 833ms vs 2400ms.

Comment: @SledgeHammer: you can actually look at the source. .NET 2.0 came with the Rotor reference source, which is still available for download. More recently, .NET Core was made open source. If you're interested, the relevant code is in [COMNumber::FormatDouble](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/775003a4c72f0acc37eab84628fcef541533ba4e/src/classlibnative/bcltype/number.cpp), which in turn defers to a piece of assembler called [DoubleToNumber](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/775003a4c72f0acc37eab84628fcef541533ba4e/src/vm/i386/fptext.asm). Profiling this is not for the faint of heart.

Comment: @JeroenMostert, yeah, ugly stuff. Doesn't seem to be any shortcuts in there since its all C++. Too bad they reparse everything every time you call... that's probably where the overhead is.

Answer (score 1):

> 2) why is the Decimal.ToString() so much faster then Double.ToString()?

1. Because `Double.ToString()` is actually much more complex. Compare the core implementation of [Decimal.ToString()](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/32f0f9721afb584b4a14d69135bea7ddc129f755/src/classlibnative/bcltype/decimal.cpp#L292) and [Double.ToString()](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/master/src/classlibnative/bcltype/number.cpp#L140), `Decimal.ToString()` has fixed precision whereas `Double.ToString()`'s precision is on demand. `Double` has its [IEEE floating point definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format) which is also much more complex than `Decimal`.
2. Current `Double.ToString()` implementation relies on `_ecvt` on Windows and [`snprintf` on Linux](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/master/src/pal/src/cruntime/misctls.cpp#L195). They're inefficient (especially for Linux implementation). There's an [in-progress PR](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/pull/12894) to re-write `Double.ToString()` in an efficient way which removes the dependency of `_ecvt` and `snprintf`.